# What's the maximum length of a type name in .NET

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum length of a C#/CLI identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186523/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-c-cli-identifier)

When generating dynamic assemblies and types, what is length restriction on the type name?

Comment: "The CLI imposes no limit on the length of names stored in metadata and subsequently processed by the CLI"

Answer (score 6):

I tested this in C#, and there is a limitation on the class names in the compiler, even if there is no limitation in the CLI.

If you declare a class name that is 511 characters, it works. If you use 512 characters you get the compiler error "Identifier too long".

Answer (score 3):

From Ecma-335, page 103:

> Metadata preserves name strings, as created by a compiler or code
>   generator, unchanged. Essentially, it treats each string as an opaque blob.
>   In particular, it preserves case. **The CLI imposes no limit on the length of
>   names stored in metadata and subsequently processed by the CLI.**

Answer (score 1):

There [doesn't appear to be one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425988/maximum-method-name-length) (that thread is about method name length, but it really applies to your question as well).