# Max length name class in c#

Tags: c#, msdn

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Maximum Method Name Length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425988/maximum-method-name-length)
>   [What is the maximum length of a C#/CLI identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186523/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-c-cli-identifier)

Just for curiosity, somebody know where I can find the max length of C# class name?

Comment: Bah, nvm. Was for methods not classes

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425988/maximum-method-name-length for **method** name length. Perhaps the same restriction applies to class names.

Comment: ^ That is for methods, not classes

Comment: There are no explicit name length restrictions in the C# spec. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186523/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-c-cli-identifier) post.

Comment: The answer is **not** about method names, but about identifiers in general and thus applies also to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no limit. But in case the file name will be the same as class name it will probably be the file system limit.