# dtSearch Filename limited to 511 characters

Tags: c#, .net, windows-server, dtsearch

While using the dtSearch Engine I ran into the problem that the file path displayed by the dtSearch FileConverter seems limited to 511 characters. This while in other parts of dtSearch the path is listed with the correct length.

I use the dtSearch .NET API version 4 to interface between my website and the dtSearch Engine. I have not set any restrictions to string length or anything. In my code the FileConverter is set to output as a string. I have tested it with the "OutputStringMaxSize" option set to `Int.MaxValue` and without any limits, but it still cuts off the file path even though it is far from any maximum length.

[Screengrab of dtSearch output from FileConverter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdHZ2.png)

Is this a limitation in dtSearch, the .NET Framework, Windows, NTFS or something else?

I use the following software:

- dtSearch Engine 7.8.9
- Windows Server 2016
- IIS 10.0

Comment: I have the exact same issue for a long time already. It seems that even enabling the "NTFS long paths" in the Group Policy doesn't fix this issue. Maybe it is some kind of maximum string limit? Can you add your "OutputString" and "OutputStringMaxSize" options used for the dtSearch Fileconverter? This might be relevant.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the maximum length of an identifier in the Visual C# compiler is 511.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Is there any way to work around this limitation? Or can this only be fixed in the dtSearch API?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson And why would such string be an identifier? And won't that throw some kind of error somehow in that case?

Comment: The number 511 just rang a bell with me. I hoped it might give you some insight into your problem.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson Do you mean as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8794978/7756921) StackOverflow post? By the comment posted below is doesn't seem to be the case since Visual Studio 2015. I have tested this with an identifier (variable name) of 10.001 characters and there were no warnings or errors.

Comment: Well, maybe it's just a coincidence that you seem to be facing a limitation of 511. But that's a big coincidence, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson It sure is a big coincidence. Almost as if it had something to do with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting dtSearch, this seems to be a limitation in the dtSearch software itself. This will be fixed in version 7.91. A release date is not yet known.

This is not a limitation in the other software that is used.
For now this is something we will have to work around.